# Functional test of email fails if tested action redirects

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing, swiftmailer

A controller action causes an e-mail to be sent and then redirects.  A functional test of this action fails due to the redirect.  If the controller is rewritten to render a template the test passes.  [This appears to be generally true; the situation can be replicated using the code in [Symfony's documentation][1]].

#### Edit: test failure

> "/usr/bin/php" "/usr/bin/phpunit" "--colors" "--log-junit"
>   "/tmp/nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--bootstrap"
>   "/home/george/volunteer/app/bootstrap.php.cache" "--configuration"
>   "/home/george/volunteer/app/phpunit.xml.dist" "--filter"
>   "%\btestActivateOrganization\b%"
>   "/home/george/netbeans-8.0.1/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php"
>   "--run=/home/george/volunteer/src/Truckee/MatchingBundle/Tests/Controller/AdminControllerTest.php"
>   PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from /home/george/volunteer/app/phpunit.xml.dist
>
> F
>
> Time: 1.36 seconds, Memory: 40.75Mb
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1)
>   Truckee\MatchingBundle\Tests\Controller\AdminControllerTest::testActivateOrganization
>   Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1.
>
> /home/george/volunteer/src/Truckee/MatchingBundle/Tests/Controller/AdminControllerTest.php:64
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
>
> Done.

#### Controller

```
public function activateOrgAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $organization = $em->getRepository("TruckeeMatchingBundle:Organization")->find($id);
    $temp = $organization->getTemp();
    if (true === $temp) {
        $organization->setTemp(false);
        $organization->setActive(true);
        $orgName = $organization->getOrgName();
        $em->persist($organization);
        $em->flush();
        $to = $em->getRepository("TruckeeMatchingBundle:Staff")->getActivePersons($id);
        $mailer = $this->container->get('admin.mailer');
        $mailer->activateOrgMail($organization, $to);
        $flash = $this->get('braincrafted_bootstrap.flash');
        $flash->success("$orgName has been activated");
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_home'));
}
```

#### Edit 3: More complete test fixture

```
class AdminControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $classes = array(
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadFocusSkillData',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadAdminUser',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadStaffUserGlenshire',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadStaffUserMelanzane',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadTemplateData',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadOpportunity',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadVolunteer',
        );
        $this->loadFixtures($classes);
        $this->client = $this->createClient();
        $this->client->followRedirects();
    }

    public function login($user)
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/login');
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form();
        $form['_username'] = $user;
        $form['_password'] = '123Abcd';
        $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

        return $crawler;
    }
    public function testActivateOrganization()
    {
        $crawler = $this->login('admin');
        $link = $crawler->selectLink('Accept organization')->link();
        $crawler = $this->client->click($link);

        $mailCollector = $this->client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
        $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());
    }
...
}
```

Comment: You write in your question *"A functional test of this action fails due to the redirect"* - Could you please elaborate how you test and how it looks like when the test fails (e.g. please show the output to stdout when you run the test via the commandline testrunner for example).

Comment: @hakre: Test output in edit above.  Test is run in Netbeans IDE as focused test method.

Comment: Try to get the profile from the previous request in history as the client already did the redirect (I assume).

Comment: @hakre: Assumption is correct.  Test `setup()` includes `$this->client->followRedirects();`.

Comment: Where's the code that creates the client?  Redirects should not be automatically followed in unit tests per Symfony documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your unit test:

```
 $this->client->followRedirects(false);
```

See the [Symfony docs on Testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#redirecting). Redirects are not followed automatically, but you are setting them to do that.  If you want to follow the next redirect after testing the email, you can callj

```
$crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```

If you want to change back to follow all redirects, call:

```
$client->followRedirects();
```

Comment: See edited test fixture above.  I make the assumption that doing `$this->client->followRedirects();` in `setup()` allows me to not include `$this->client->followRedirect();` everywhere a redirect might occur in this fixture.

Comment: The `setUp()` function recreates in the client for every unit test, so if you don't want it to follow for a specific test, then just add `$this->client->follow Redirects(false);` at the top of that individual test

Comment: Fascinating! A judicious placement of `$this->client->followRedirects(false);` (i.e., not necessarily at the top!) allows the test to pass.  Big thanks.